# Could not change the font color after adding mat-sort-header using Angular Datatable

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using one `Angular data table` where I am populating the data. But after adding `mat-sort-header` I can change the font color of the header text. I am explaining my code below.

```
<section id="main-content">
  <section class="wrapper upload-data-templates">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group has-search" style="padding-top: 38px;margin-left: 15px;">
        <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback" style="margin-top: 13px;"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search By Report Name" style="height: 46px;width: 180%;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">

          <!-- Position Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
          </ng-container>
      
          <!-- Name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
      
          <!-- Weight Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="download">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Download </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
              <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Log</a> |
              <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Data report</a> |
              <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">HTML report</a>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
      
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
      
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                       showFirstLastButtons 
                       aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
        </mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

And I am using the following `CSS` code.

```
.section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #fff;
}








table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mat-h1{
  margin-top:2%;
  margin-left:1%;
}
.mat-header-cell{
  font-size:medium;
}
.pull-right.mt-3{
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-right:15px;
}
.mat-elevation-z8 {
  width: 100%;
}

.pull-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.padding-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}


.mat-table {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.mat-header-row {
background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.05);
}

.mat-header-row th {
border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

.mat-header-row th:last-child {
border-right: none; 
}

.mat-row td {
border-right: 1px dotted #ccc; 
}

.mat-row td:last-child {
border-right: none; 
}

.mat-row td, .mat-header-row th {
padding-left: 20px !important; 
}

.mat-icon {
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 5px;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.mat-icon:hover {
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

button:focus { outline: none !important; }




.mat-table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.mat-header-row {
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.05);
}

.mat-header-row th {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

.mat-header-row th:last-child {
  border-right: none; 
}

.mat-row td {
  border-right: 1px dotted #ccc; 
}

.mat-row td:last-child {
  border-right: none; 
}

.mat-row td, .mat-header-row th {
  padding-left: 20px !important; 
}

.mat-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
  
  .mat-icon:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  }

  .has-search .form-control {
    padding-left: 2.375rem;
}

.has-search .form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 2.375rem;
    height: 2.375rem;
    line-height: 2.375rem;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;
}

.mat-header-row {
  background: #005173;
  color: white;
}
```

And is generating the table like below.

[image]

Here the header `text` are not visible and I wanted to make it to `white` . I have added also `.mat-header-row { background: #005173; color: white;}` but its not working if I will remove `mat-sort-header` then its working fine. Here I need to add `white` color to both `header text and sort arrow key`. Is there any expert who can help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I did a lil research but im no angular dev. Try giving them a custom class and using that to apply the color instead of using a pre-existing framework class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this styling rule for both header text and arrow as below:

```
.mat-header-row {
  background-color: #005173;
}

th.mat-sort-header {
  color: white;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
  color: white;
}
```

Note: The arrow will only turn to white color when the column is sorted.

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bumrzw)